# Json returning a lists within a list

Tags: c#, json, datacontractserializer

I am new to using JSON and I am struggling to return specifically a list, within a list. I get the following JSON:

```
{
    "parameters": {
        "tbdb": "trudon",
        "min_prefix_length": "2",
        "service": "prefix",
        "template": "service.json",
        "term_prefix": "plu"},
    "termHints": [
        {
            "name": "Plumbers & Sanitary Engineers",
            "id":"209654",
            "values": {
                "value":"Plumbers & Sanitary Engineers",
                "pre_em":"",
                "em":"Plu",
                "post_em":"mbers & Sanitary Engineers",
                "nature":"PT",
                "id":"209654"
            }
        },
    ],
    "facets": [
        {
            "id":"209654",
            "name":"Plumbers & Sanitary Engineers"
        }
    ],
    "total":1
}
```

I have desrialized this using the the JSON *DataContractJsonSerializer* and it looks like the following:

*edited: made the changes that were suggested by carlosfigueira here*

```
    [DataContract]
    public class AutoCompleteResponse
    {
        [DataMember(Name = "parameters")]
        public Parameter Parameters { get; set; }
        [DataMember(Name = "termHints")]
        public List<termHints> hints { get; set; }
        [DataMember(Name = "total")]
        public string Total { get; set; }
    }
    [DataContract]
    public class Parameter
    {
        [DataMember(Name = "tbdb")]
        public string tbdb { get; set; }
        [DataMember(Name = "min_prefix_length")]
        public string min_prefix_length { get; set; }
        [DataMember(Name = "service")]
        public string service { get; set; }
        [DataMember(Name = "template")]
        public string template { get; set; }
        [DataMember(Name = "term_prefix")]
        public string term_prefrix { get; set; }
    }
    [DataContract]
    public class termHints
    {
        [DataMember(Name = "name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [DataMember(Name = "id")]
        public string id { get; set; }
        [DataMember(Name = "values")]
        public values Values { get; set; }
        [DataMember(Name = "facets")]
        public facets Facets { get; set; }

    }
    [DataContract]
    public class values
    {
        [DataMember(Name = "value")]
        public string value_name { get; set; }
        [DataMember(Name = "pre_em")]
        public string pre_em { get; set; }
        [DataMember(Name = "em")]
        public string em { get; set; }
        [DataMember(Name = "post_em")]
        public string post_em { get; set; }
        [DataMember(Name = "nature")]
        public string nature { get; set; }
        [DataMember(Name = "id")]
        public string value_id { get; set; }
    }
    [DataContract]
    public class facets
    {
        [DataMember(Name = "id")]
        public string facet_id { get; set; }
        [DataMember (Name = "name")]
        public string facet_name {get; set; }
    }
```

The serialization I do looks like the following:

```
    WebClient w = new WebClient();
    w.DownloadStringCompleted += (a, b) =>
    {
        // Check for errors
        if (b == null) { return; }
        if (b.Error != null) { return; }
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(b.Result)) { return; }

        // Desearealize from JSON to .NET objects
        Byte[] bytes = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(b.Result);
        MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream(bytes);
        DataContractJsonSerializer dataContractJsonSerializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(AutoCompleteResponse));
        AutoCompleteResponse autocompleteSearchResponse = dataContractJsonSerializer.ReadObject(memoryStream) as AutoCompleteResponse;
        memoryStream.Close();

        // Raise Event
        this.OnSearchCompleted(
            new WhatEventArgs()
            {
                response = autocompleteSearchResponse
            }
        );
    };
    w.DownloadStringAsync(builder.Uri);
```

The return I create looks like the following:

```
    public class WhatEventArgs : EventArgs
    {
        public AutoCompleteResponse response { get; set; }
    }
```

*edit: adding the code that is used to get the data here incase this is helpful... This is how I am getting the data from the values, perhaps I am doing something wrong but I am not getting any data (it's null) and I have no idea what I have done wrong *

```
    protected void cmdSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        AutocompleteWhat search = new AutocompleteWhat()
        {
            Num = 2
        };
        search.SearchCompleted += (a, b) =>
        {
            List<values> _value = new List<values>();
            foreach (termHints item in b.response.hints)
            {
                _value.Add(item.Values);
            }
            if (_value.Count > 0)
            {
                dgvResults.DataSource = _value;
            }
            else
            {
                dgvResults.DataSource = null;
            }
            dgvResults.DataBind();
        };
        search.Search("plu");
    }
```

I now need to get the actual values from hints, however the data returned from values is empty. I have no idea why, please see if you can see what I can not see.

*edit* Fixed the Json, was missing the closing ] for "facets"

Comment: Could you add the code where you actually do deserialization, thanks

Comment: Code has been added... I do like lists ;)

Comment: I can never take JSON seriously. First thing that comes to my mind is PRESS X TO JASON. Downhill shenanigans from thereon.

Comment: I have managed to deserialize your json string as is; values was not null. Haven't had the time to pass through all your code but it seems to me that the deserialization is not the issue.

Comment: What's null exactly, the whole response object or just every single item.Values?

Comment: Hi, sorry took so long to reply, with the way the code looks currently, if I were to make the datasource of a gridview equal to hints it will populate id and name, however, if I were to create a list, List<Values>, and populate it with hints.value (code in the last code block of the example above) I only get empty values, so I get a data grid with titles and no values...its like values.value = "";... that is what I mean, don't know if you understand what I am saying

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the `DataContractJsonSerializer` to work you need to have the a type system with the schema which matches the JSON. The "values" field isn't a list (or an array) - it's another JSON object, so you don't need to declare it as a `List<Value>` - it's just a Value object there.

Also, the DataMember Name properties on the termHints class are set to 'Values' and 'Facets' for their respective members, but in the json the names are in lower case, so you'll need to change that as well (DataMember(Name = "values") and DataMember(Name = "facets").

**Update with code**

Another problem I see in the code / JSON is that in the JSON document, `facets` is a sibling of `termHints`, but in the data contracts you have, the facets are a child of the hints. So one of those needs to be changed. Below is a code with both versions, just pick one :)

```
public class StackOverflow_6747339
{
    class FacetsAsSiblingOfHints
    {
        [DataContract]
        public class AutoCompleteResponse
        {
            [DataMember(Name = "parameters")]
            public Parameter Parameters { get; set; }
            [DataMember(Name = "termHints")]
            public List<TermHints> Hints { get; set; }
            [DataMember(Name = "facets")]
            public List<Facets> Facets { get; set; }
            [DataMember(Name = "total")]
            public string Total { get; set; }

            public override string ToString()
            {
                return string.Format("AutoCompleteResponse[Parameters={0},hints={1},facets={2},total={3}]",
                    Parameters, ListToString(Hints), ListToString(Facets), Total);
            }
        }
        [DataContract]
        public class Parameter
        {
            [DataMember(Name = "tbdb")]
            public string tbdb { get; set; }
            [DataMember(Name = "min_prefix_length")]
            public string min_prefix_length { get; set; }
            [DataMember(Name = "service")]
            public string service { get; set; }
            [DataMember(Name = "template")]
            public string template { get; set; }
            [DataMember(Name = "term_prefix")]
            public string term_prefrix { get; set; }

            public override string ToString()
            {
                return string.Format("Parameter[tbdb={0},min_prefix_length={1},service={2},template={3},term_prefix={4}]",
                    tbdb, min_prefix_length, service, template, term_prefrix);
            }
        }
        [DataContract]
        public class TermHints
        {
            [DataMember(Name = "name")]
            public string Name { get; set; }
            [DataMember(Name = "id")]
            public string Id { get; set; }
            [DataMember(Name = "values")]
            public Values Values { get; set; }

            public override string ToString()
            {
                return string.Format("TermHints[Name={0},Id={1},Values={2}]", Name, Id, Values);
            }
        }
        [DataContract]
        public class Values
        {
            [DataMember(Name = "value")]
            public string value_name { get; set; }
            [DataMember(Name = "pre_em")]
            public string pre_em { get; set; }
            [DataMember(Name = "em")]
            public string em { get; set; }
            [DataMember(Name = "post_em")]
            public string post_em { get; set; }
            [DataMember(Name = "nature")]
            public string nature { get; set; }
            [DataMember(Name = "id")]
            public string value_id { get; set; }

            public override string ToString()
            {
                return string.Format("Values[value_name={0},pre_em={1},em={2},post_em={3},nature={4},value_id={5}]",
                    value_name, pre_em, em, post_em, nature, value_id);
            }
        }
        [DataContract]
        public class Facets
        {
            [DataMember(Name = "id")]
            public string facet_id { get; set; }
            [DataMember(Name = "name")]
            public string facet_name { get; set; }

            public override string ToString()
            {
                return string.Format("Facets[facet_id={0},facet_name={1}]", facet_id, facet_name);
            }
        }

        const string json = @"{
""parameters"": {
    ""tbdb"": ""trudon"",
    ""min_prefix_length"": ""2"",
    ""service"": ""prefix"",
    ""template"": ""service.json"",
    ""term_prefix"": ""plu""},
""termHints"": [
    {
        ""name"": ""Plumbers & Sanitary Engineers"",
        ""id"":""209654"",
        ""values"": {
            ""value"":""Plumbers & Sanitary Engineers"",
            ""pre_em"":"""",
            ""em"":""Plu"",
            ""post_em"":""mbers & Sanitary Engineers"",
            ""nature"":""PT"",
            ""id"":""209654""
        }
    },
],
""facets"": [
    {
        ""id"":""209654"",
        ""name"":""Plumbers & Sanitary Engineers""
    }
],
""total"":1
}";

        internal static void Test()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Facets as siblings of the hints");
            DataContractJsonSerializer dcjs = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(AutoCompleteResponse));
            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(json));
            AutoCompleteResponse obj = (AutoCompleteResponse)dcjs.ReadObject(ms);
            ms.Close();
            Console.WriteLine(obj);
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
    }

    class FacetsInsideHints
    {
        [DataContract]
        public class AutoCompleteResponse
        {
            [DataMember(Name = "parameters")]
            public Parameter Parameters { get; set; }
            [DataMember(Name = "termHints")]
            public List<TermHints> Hints { get; set; }
            [DataMember(Name = "total")]
            public string Total { get; set; }

            public override string ToString()
            {
                return string.Format("AutoCompleteResponse[Parameters={0},hints={1},total={2}]",
                    Parameters, ListToString(Hints), Total);
            }
        }
        [DataContract]
        public class Parameter
        {
            [DataMember(Name = "tbdb")]
            public string tbdb { get; set; }
            [DataMember(Name = "min_prefix_length")]
            public string min_prefix_length { get; set; }
            [DataMember(Name = "service")]
            public string service { get; set; }
            [DataMember(Name = "template")]
            public string template { get; set; }
            [DataMember(Name = "term_prefix")]
            public string term_prefrix { get; set; }

            public override string ToString()
            {
                return string.Format("Parameter[tbdb={0},min_prefix_length={1},service={2},template={3},term_prefix={4}]",
                    tbdb, min_prefix_length, service, template, term_prefrix);
            }
        }
        [DataContract]
        public class TermHints
        {
            [DataMember(Name = "name")]
            public string Name { get; set; }
            [DataMember(Name = "id")]
            public string Id { get; set; }
            [DataMember(Name = "values")]
            public Values Values { get; set; }
            [DataMember(Name = "facets")]
            public List<Facets> Facets { get; set; }

            public override string ToString()
            {
                return string.Format("TermHints[Name={0},Id={1},Values={2},Facets={3}]", Name, Id, Values, ListToString(Facets));
            }
        }
        [DataContract]
        public class Values
        {
            [DataMember(Name = "value")]
            public string value_name { get; set; }
            [DataMember(Name = "pre_em")]
            public string pre_em { get; set; }
            [DataMember(Name = "em")]
            public string em { get; set; }
            [DataMember(Name = "post_em")]
            public string post_em { get; set; }
            [DataMember(Name = "nature")]
            public string nature { get; set; }
            [DataMember(Name = "id")]
            public string value_id { get; set; }

            public override string ToString()
            {
                return string.Format("Values[value_name={0},pre_em={1},em={2},post_em={3},nature={4},value_id={5}]",
                    value_name, pre_em, em, post_em, nature, value_id);
            }
        }
        [DataContract]
        public class Facets
        {
            [DataMember(Name = "id")]
            public string facet_id { get; set; }
            [DataMember(Name = "name")]
            public string facet_name { get; set; }

            public override string ToString()
            {
                return string.Format("Facets[facet_id={0},facet_name={1}]", facet_id, facet_name);
            }
        }

        const string json = @"{
""parameters"": {
    ""tbdb"": ""trudon"",
    ""min_prefix_length"": ""2"",
    ""service"": ""prefix"",
    ""template"": ""service.json"",
    ""term_prefix"": ""plu""},
""termHints"": [
    {
        ""name"": ""Plumbers & Sanitary Engineers"",
        ""id"":""209654"",
        ""values"": {
            ""value"":""Plumbers & Sanitary Engineers"",
            ""pre_em"":"""",
            ""em"":""Plu"",
            ""post_em"":""mbers & Sanitary Engineers"",
            ""nature"":""PT"",
            ""id"":""209654""
        },
        ""facets"": [
            {
                ""id"":""209654"",
                ""name"":""Plumbers & Sanitary Engineers""
            }
        ]
    },
],
""total"":1
}";

        internal static void Test()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Facets inside the hints");
            DataContractJsonSerializer dcjs = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(AutoCompleteResponse));
            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(json));
            AutoCompleteResponse obj = (AutoCompleteResponse)dcjs.ReadObject(ms);
            ms.Close();
            Console.WriteLine(obj);
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
    }

    static string ListToString<T>(List<T> list)
    {
        if (list == null)
        {
            return "<<null>>";
        }

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.Append("[");
        for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
        {
            if (i > 0) sb.Append(",");
            sb.Append(list[i]);
        }

        sb.Append("]");
        return sb.ToString();
    }

    public static void Test()
    {
        FacetsAsSiblingOfHints.Test();
        FacetsInsideHints.Test();
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok, I made the suggested changes to the code, I kind of misunderstood what you suggested initially but figured it out after a cup of coffee. The problem now is that the value class is not returning any result, its all empty... any idea why? So close to a solution, it will probably slap me in the face.. I have updated the code.. should probably change the title aswell..